# Code coverage in Java with EclEmma not scanning expecting exception methods

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, eclemma

I'm trying to get my code coverage in java, using Eclipse and EclEmma.

My tests are using JUnit 4 and I've got some tests looking like this :

```
    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void createTime_withInvalidMinuteUnder0_throws(){
    //Arrange
    ...
    //Act
    Something triggering IllegalArgumentException Here       
}
```

And EclEmma says that the test fails because there's an IllegalArgumentException being thrown. So it drops my code coverage indicator even though it's supposed to throw something. Is there an option to make it see that JUnit expected exception tag ?

edit: I've found out that if you add the throw to the declaration of the test aswell, it works!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, there is no way to get EclEmma to notice the `expected` clause. They acknowledge this fact [here](http://www.eclemma.org/faq.html#trouble05).

> **Why are JUnit4 test cases with expected exceptions shown as not covered?**
>
> JUnit4 test cases with expected exceptions are shown as not covered even though they were executed. The reason for this is that underlying JaCoCo code coverage library only considers code as executed when certain probes are executed. For successful test cases marked with `@Test{expected=...}` this is not the case.

Personally, I wouldn't worry too much about it. Coverage of test cases is the least interesting thing EclEmma can tell you; I always completely ignore those metrics and focus on the coverage of my production code.

Comment: What are more interesting things EclEmma can tell me?

Comment: I was referring to the code coverage metrics for your production code, rather than your test code. Or did I misunderstand your original question?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I misunderstood your statement in your answer.

Comment: Your tests does have to be covered, just exception cases are not covered by eclemma.

Answer (score 5):

Can't comment yet, but I wanted to point out, in relation to the accepted answer, that there's a very good reason to pay attention to coverage of your test code.

It's just way too easy with *JUnit* to screw up the test method naming convention or forget the @Test annotation (depending on your *JUnit* version). Do that, and you could easily be fooled into thinking that your solid green bar means that the nice test you just added passed, when in fact it never ran. Coverage coloring will show this very prominently. Except of course, as this thread points out, some of your tests that throw exceptions might look like they didn't run when they did.