# EclEmma fails to count method that throws an exception as covered

Tags: java, code-coverage, eclemma

I am not getting to the 100% code covered and would like to. Unless I see the 100% green I wonder what I forget to test and go hunting only to find out silly things based on the tool and not my test are keeping me from it.  Then later I forget and have to rinse/repeat.

While all paths are covered in testThrow because of the exception it is not counted as run.

Is there a way to re-write it so it is seen as covered towards that elusive 100% green.

```
public class Dummy {
    public void testThrow() throws Exception {
        throwException();       // This line is red and is seen as not covered.
    }

    private void throwException() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}

public class DummyTest() {
    @Test
    public void testThrow() throws Exception {
        new Dummy().testThrow();
    }
}
```

I added @Test(expected=Exception.class) but the line is still red.

I also tried:

```
public void testThrow() throws Exception {
    try {
        throwException();       // This line is STILL red
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        throw e;                // This line becomes green (as expected)
    }
}                               // This line is now also red
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `@Test` with `@Test(expected = Exception.class)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code coverage in Java with EclEmma not scanning expecting exception methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757559/code-coverage-in-java-with-eclemma-not-scanning-expecting-exception-methods)

Comment: Added: @Test(expected = Exception.class) but still is red.  Other post is about the testcase being red which is a known issue with testing code due to the way the tool plugs in.  I aknowledge that and in general ignore them.  My issue is the method under test (not the unit test) is red.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the same thing in [EclEmma documentation](http://www.eclemma.org/faq.html):

> ### **Why are JUnit4 test cases with expected exceptions shown as not covered?**
>
> JUnit4 test cases with expected exceptions are shown as not covered
>   even though they were executed. The reason for this is that underlying
>   JaCoCo code coverage library only considers code as executed when
>   certain probes are executed. For successful test cases marked with
>   @Test{expected=...} this is not the case.